# Javascript get value from html class name in for loop not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
foreach($products as $row){
  <input type="hidden" class="prodId" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" class="prodUnique" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>">
  <button id="added" onClick="addToCart()" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><i class="icon-basket"></i> Add to Cart</span></button>
}

<script>
function addToCart(){
   var id = $(".prodId").val();
   var unique = $(".prodUnique").val();
   console.log(id);
}
</scritp>
```

Every time it is showing only first product ID. Means the id's are getting displayed properly in HTML, But When I console it in javascript, It shows same id.
Suppose there are 4 products with ID 100, 101, 103, 105 displaying, then whenever I click on any product, the value every time getting consoled in javascript is 100.

Comment: That selector will return a list of objects that you have to loop on and get the value.

Comment: Because in HTML on class denotes a set of objects. Multiple element can belong to the same class.

Comment: Can u please show with basic code example?

Comment: Also note that you use an id as a static value in a loop. This will result in multiple elements with the same id for your button. This is not allowed in HTML as every id needs to be unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing something like this,

```
$(".someClassSelector").each((key, element) => {
    let value = $(element).val();
    /*
        Use your logic
    */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a JavaScript method.

So you are looping `$products` with 2 inputs and a button where the PHP has executed long ago, on the server-side... Long before the begining of the execution of the JS. That means the values **are the same** for each iteration of that client-side loop.

More reading on this other SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840431/2159528

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling function you can have click event on click of button and pick values by custom attributes. Refer code.

```
foreach($products as $row){
  <button id="added" prodUnique="<?php echo $unique; ?>" prodId="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><i class="icon-basket"></i> Add to Cart</span></button>
}

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.added').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('prodId');
        var unique = $(this).attr('prodUnique')
        console.log(id);
    });
});
</scritp>
```